# Is there any difference between "T" and "const T" in template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, syntax, constants

Is there any difference between following 2 syntax:

```
template<int N> struct A;         // (1)
```

and

```
template<const int N> struct A;   // (2)
```

Any general guideline for when to use each syntax ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

No.

`§14.1 [temp.param] p5`

> [...] The top-level *cv-qualifiers* on the *template-parameter* are ignored when determining its type.

Comment: Is that for `typename` parameter kind only ? (See my answer). I do not have access to the standard and I am rather bad at finding useful information in the draft I have.

Comment: @J.N.: No, this quote specifically refers to non-type template parameters (you can't have a `const typename` anyways :P).

Comment: Accepting your answer. You may want to update the coding guidelines for the sake of completeness.

Comment: @iammilind: Which coding guidelines are you talking about?

Comment: Though, it's implied that `const` is not useful in *any* case, your answer just talks about the comparison between them. It's worth mentioning when to use which version (i.e. always use 1st). It's your wish :). This is just for reference for the future/novice visitors.

Comment: BTW for the C++20 standard this quote can be found in §14.1 [temp.param] p6.

Answer (score 7):

I found this doing a quick search of the standard:

```
template<const short cs> class B { };
template<short s> void g(B<s>);
void k2() {
    B<1> b;
    g(b); // OK: cv-qualiﬁers are ignored on template parameter types
}
```

The comment says they are ignored.

I'll recommend not using `const` in template parameters as it's unnecessary. Note that it's not 'implied' either - they're constant expressions which is different from `const`.

Comment: Comments are not normative.

Answer (score 2):

The choice of `int` was probably a bad idea, it makes a difference for pointers though:

```
class A
{
public:
    int Counter;
};

A a;


template <A* a>
struct Coin
{
    static void DoStuff()
    {
        ++a->Counter; // won't compile if using const A* !!
    }
};

Coin<&a>::DoStuff();
cout << a.Counter << endl;
```

Comment: Funnily enough the standard seems to disagree with my compiler (GCC 4.6.1 / ubuntu) if I am to believe other people's answers :/

Comment: No worries, I may aswell be misinterpreting the standard. And @Pubby's answer only indicates that it's ignored when matching templates.

Comment: `const A*`  is not the `const` qualified version of `A*`. It is an unrelated type.  `A* const` is the `const` qualified version of `A*`.