# Template function argument as 'const T'

Tags: c++, templates, constants

I was given the template function that is a member function in class `CompactWriter`:

```
template<typename T>
CompactWriter operator%(const Field<const T>& field)
{
    _os << field.getName() << ": " << field.valueReference() << ", ";
    return *this;
}
```

And then, I was asked what was the second const for.
I know that according to this : [Is there any difference between “T” and “const T” in template parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679116/is-there-any-difference-between-t-and-const-t-in-template-parameter) There should be no difference.
Therefore, I'm kind of confused of why this question was asked.

A little background hoping this might trigger something for you that I might have missed...
Template Class 'Field':

```
#ifndef SERIALIZATION_FIELD_H
#define SERIALIZATION_FIELD_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Field
{
private:
public:

    Field(const std::string& name, T& value)
            : _name(name)
            , _value(value)
    {}

    const std::string& getName() const { return _name; }
    T& valueReference() const { return _value; }

private:
    std::string _name;
    T& _value;
};

template<typename T> const Field<T> field(const std::string& name, T& value)
{
    return Field<T>(name, value);
}

#endif //SERIALIZATION_FIELD_H
```

And the operator calls were made in `main.cpp`:

```
const std::string name = "Dan";
const int age = 35;
const double weight = 30 + sqrt(2);

CompactWriter writer(std::cout); // Initialize a writer object.

writer.open();

writer % field("Name", name)
        % field("Age", age)
        % field("Weight", weight);

writer.close();
return 0;
```

The functions `writer.open()` and `writer.close()` do nothing except adding to cout `{` and `}`.

If anybody could point me to a reason why is the second `const` in the operator overload `%` member function header is there, it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

That question is being asked in a *completely different context*. The `const` you have here is significant. Otherwise, it would not be legal to use Fields of a `const` template parameter type.

Comment: So it all depends on the initialized parameters in the `main.cpp` that are called `name`, `age`, `weight` ?

Comment: Because even if that `const` is removed, the operator function would still run normally on the `const` initialized parameters in `main.cpp`.