# function taking vector, index and returning element

Tags: c++, vector, reference

The following will work fine, until I need a non-const reference:

```
template <typename T>
T const& get(std::vector<T> const& vec, size_t i) { return vec[i]; }
```

If I change return type to `T &`, then something like `get(vec, 0).push_back(3)` will work (if `vec` is a vector of vectors of integers). However, if accessing a vector of integers (instead of a vector of vectors), we get:

```
error: binding ‘const value_type {aka const int}’
to reference of type ‘int&’ discards qualifiers
```

Is there a way to make both work with the same function?

**Update:** the suggestion given in the answer below works, except for `vector<bool>`. I am posting here the details for it:

```
 template <typename T>
 T const& get(std::vector<T> const& vec, size_t i) { return vec[i]; }

 template <typename T>
 T & get(std::vector<T> & vec, size_t i) { return vec[i]; }

 int main() {
    std::vector<bool> vec_bool{true,true,false};
    std::cout << get(vec_bool, 0) << std::endl;
 }
```

Compiling with `g++ --std=c++11 test.cc` gives:

```
 test.cc: In instantiation of ‘T& get(std::vector<T>&, size_t) [with T = bool; size_t = long unsigned int]’:
 test.cc:12:30:   required from here
 test.cc:8:55: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘bool&’ from an rvalue of type ‘bool’
  T & get(std::vector<T> & vec, size_t i) { return vec[i]; }
                                                        ^
 In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/vector:65:0,
                  from test.cc:1:
 /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_bvector.h:80:5: note:   after user-defined conversion: std::_Bit_reference::operator bool() const
      operator bool() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
```

Compiler version: g++ (Ubuntu 5.3.1-10ubuntu2) 5.3.1 20160225

Comment: There should be no difference between a vector of vectors and a vector if `int`. Please post an MCVE.

Comment: Are you sure it will work for a vector of vectors? It shouldn't

Comment: Are you sure that you are not trying to access a vector of `const int`? The error message indicates you do.

Comment: From what I can see, this is a textbook example of indirection instead of abstraction. Why do you want to have a `get(vector, index)` function when you can always just say `vector[index]`? What is special about your use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::vector` offers [two overloads](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/) for the `operator[]`, the non-const and the const version.

As your `get` function takes a const vector, indexing the vector will always call the const version of `operator[]`, which returns a const reference. Thus there is a mismatch with the return type as you cannot convert a `const int` to an `int&`, or a `const vector<vector<...>>` to a `vector<vector<...>>&`. I wonder how you didn't get an error when using a vector of vectors.

You would have to provide two versions of this function. One that takes a non-const vector and returns a non-const reference, and the other one, which you already provided, that takes a const vector and returns a const reference.

And that would be the same as using the standard `operator[]` but with an additional layer of indirection.

Edit: Also see this question - [Is there any difference between “T” and “const T” in template parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679116/is-there-any-difference-between-t-and-const-t-in-template-parameter)

Comment: "... but with an additional layer of indirection" This might be the most important detail in your answer. I still would like to know why exactly would that indirection be necessary (as some kind of compatibility layer maybe?).

Comment: It works, except for `vector<bool>`, which is likely connected to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_container_%28C%2B%2B%29#Specialization_for_bool.

Comment: @Boris I can see this being used as a wrapper to the `operator[]` to check for index validity..

Comment: @LasseKliemann `vector<bool>`'s implementation uses an optimization to fit each boolean into 1 bit instead of 1 byte, so the `operator[]` returns a proxy reference which is not the same a `bool&`. Still, post what compiler you used and what code you used in your tests so that we can see what exactly is going on.

Comment: Regarding the purpose: there is a `class A` that is mainly used to hold an index `A.i`. For an instance `A a` and vector `vec`, we can write `vec[a.i]`. However, in my application it would look more natural to say `a.get(vec)`. This eventually requires the functionality I was asking for.