# Template const/non-const argument cast

Tags: c++, templates

I went through some searches but couldn't quite find this one. Consider this situation:

```
template <class T> class TemplClass;
void a_function(TemplClass<const X>&);

TemplClass<X> inst;
a_function( inst ); // fails
```

"invalid initialization of reference of type ‘TemplClass&’ from expression of type ‘TemplClass’"

The situation is 100% safe as far as I can tell. Still, C++ does not allow this. So I wonder what cast to use instead of the trivial C-cast.

```
a_function( static_cast<TemplClass<const X>&>(inst) ); // fails, similar error message

a_function( reinterpret_cast<TemplClass<const X>&>(inst) ); // works
```

dynamic_cast is out of the question, const_cast fails too (and rightly so).

The reinterpret_cast feels fishy (is it though?). But is there a solution with some kind of trick that I missed? Anyone know why the standard does not simply detect that this is something good? Or is there something 'bad' about this cast?

Comment: `TemplClass<const X>` has no relation to `TemplClass<X>`; they are completely different types.

Comment: `The situation is 100% safe` In your case yes. In general no

Comment: Techincally, yes - but is there any reason why the function would do something unintended? Like not work , crash, change stuff that shouldn't be changed?

Comment: I understand the following: other functions may be called (const rather than non-const). The reverse would not be good (if the function signature is non-const). I just cannot think of a situation where this is a 'bad' thing.

Comment: your reasoning applies to `const TemplClass<X>&`

Comment: No, I do not think so. It's totally different.

Comment: in what way your use-case would be different? why would you expect the same logic applicable to all class templates taking a type template parameter? how can you know where and how is `T` used ?

Comment: I use this casting a lot when T is (eventually) only used as a pointer. Then nothing changes, the cast is valid. But I cannot think of *any* usage where this would fail, so my guess is that it's always safe.

Comment: if `T` is used as a pointer, then use `std::propagate_const` and `const TemplClass<X>&`

Comment: Use case: Ehhh ... you have a vector<X*>. You want to use a tool that just queries your objects: it expects a vector<const X*>. So the only thing that happens is that you are guaranteed that you objects will not be changed. What do you do? Make a new vector<const X*> just to call the tool?

Comment: @BertBril there are dozens of ways to avoid that problem (most of which are : don't make a function which takes `vector<const X*>` in the first place. Use iterator ranges.)

Comment: In this situation it's safe, but templates are used for more than containers of ```T```. The point is, with all the possibilities of templates, the compiler has no idea how to convert ```TemplClass<X>``` into ```TempClass<const X>``` for **any** given template.

Comment: @m-m absolutely. If I can influence it. But sometimes you simply need a vector<const X*> and you are working with a vector<X*> in your own stuff. The cast is trivial and safe.

Comment: The only use-case you mention is that for const propagation from pointer types to pointed types, for that, use `propagate_const`

Comment: @BertBril define safe, because doing that with vectors and a reinterpret_cast is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @JornVernee I have a hard time imagining any situation where this could go wrong, so please show me ..? And whether it's hard for the compiler ... at least I can simply cast and it works ...

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki could you show how that works? is is pre-C++11? I see it's std::experimental:: ...

Comment: @BertBril http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6264eb8bf4db569

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679116/is-there-any-difference-between-t-and-const-t-in-template-parameter

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Still pretty confused. My use case is that I'm stuck with  library functions that expect a vector<const T*> reference. I don't see how propagate_const would be usable.

Comment: @tobi303 the linked question is for non-type template parameters

Comment: @tobi303 your 'related' is certainly related but I saw it; and I know there is a difference. But as far as I know there is no practical flip side to simply casting - in any case. I just can;t think up a case where it would be harmful.

Comment: @BertBril blame those who declare a function taking vector<const T*>

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki No software will ever be released by means of blaming others. The world is as it is, and we get stuff done.

Comment: you blame language designers for not considering *such an obvious and safe use-case*, well...

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki do I blame? where?

Comment: You could use conversion operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TemplClass<const T>` and `TemplClass<T>` are unrelated types.

For example you may have (partial) specialization to make them really different:

```
template<typename T>
class TemplClass
{
    void generic();
    std::string s;
};

template<typename T>
class TemplClass<const T>
{
    void foo();
    std::vector<int> v;
};
```

Casting one into the other doesn't make sense.

In the same way

```
class A
{
    char* p;
};

class B
{
    char* p;
};
```

Those 2 classes are unrelated (even if it seems identical).

Comment: Thx, that's it.. Your first example shows where things may go wrong. The second one shows what C++ thinks about the classes, not what I can do with them.

Answer (score 3):

> But is there a solution with some kind of trick that I missed?

The ideal solution is to not write such restricted template interfaces. For example, consider the standard library algorithms that take iterators to represent ranges rather than specific template types with specific object types.

If you're unable to fix the interface as it's say in a third party library, then you're going to be stuck copying your `Templ<X>` to a `Templ<const X>` before making the call.

> Anyone know why the standard does not simply detect that this is
>   something good?

Because it's not good. The very simplest case is where there are template specializations where it would change some meaning/functionality. The compiler can't simply change the instantiation of the template.

> Or is there something 'bad' about this cast?

By the language, the cast is illegal because the const and non-const template instantiations are unrelated types. Depending on the actual case, there are probably legal alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for this; I agree that if you go for the modern C++ paradigms, then iterators are way better. But a lot of code is simply based on other paradigms, some of which have their own merits.

Comment: In fact, I disagree with one part: the part that 'X' and 'const X' are different types. They are, but they are also not. They have all sorts of differences, but in the end it boils down to the same types. I guess you could say that the 'const' system is a different dimension in the type system. And in that dimension, it is always OK to use something that is non-const for things that are const.

Comment: So, I admit that everyone is right in saying that they are, de-facto, different types. But I fail to see how C++ helps me here, and in the end, I can only see that I can cast and it works fine. I'd like to see a counterexample, and figure out what are the conditions that such a cast will fail to be good.