# Purpose of const-qualified template values

Tags: c++, c++20

Considering this is a legal synthax:

```cpp
template <const auto value>
void do_stuff()
{}
```

What is the purpose of the template value **const-qualifier**?
*To me, none. But I love suprises.*

Comment: Maybe? it stops you from passing the template parameter as a non-const lvalue reference?  Haven't tested.  Seems silly to add the const qualification to me.

Comment: Well, is this legal synthax at first ?

Comment: It should be legal per: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.param#6

Comment: I suspect that it's a case of "allowing it does no harm and means we don't have to add code for a special case".

Comment: dupe of [Is there any difference between "T" and "const T" in template parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679116/is-there-any-difference-between-t-and-const-t-in-template-parameter)

Comment: in addition to what molbdnilo wrote I suspect that it is similar to `const` on function declarations `void foo(const int)` makes no difference on the declaration but still you can put a `const` there (it does make a difference on the definition)