# GCC vs Clang & MSVC Bug while using non type template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, language-lawyer, non-type-template-parameter

I was writing a rather simple example to clarify(better understand) the concept of non type template parameters. The example is shown below. To my surprise, the given example compiles with MSVC and Clang but fails to compile with GCC(for both C++14 & C++17).

```
template<typename T, T a>
void f()
{
      decltype(a) p; //is this valid given the call expression f<const int, 0>() below
}
int main()
{
     f<const int,0>();
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/T33hehE1z)

Which compiler is right here according to the standard.

Comment: Dup of [Is there any difference between "T" and "const T" in template parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679116/is-there-any-difference-between-t-and-const-t-in-template-parameter)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I read that post before posting my question(see in my answer below i have quoted [temp.param#5] and also already knew about the difference between `T` and `const T` in template parameter. I have explained the reason in my answer below. I admit i may be wrong in interpreting [temp.param#5] as stated in my answer. That is, the dup does not answer my question.

Comment: I'm tempted to close as a dupe too, but don't want to hammer this single-handedly. The standard says *"when **determining** the type"*, not "when deducing", so I believe it applies always, and not only when deducing the type.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat [temp.param#6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.param#5) should be made more clear. In particular, "specifying the type" is not the same as "determining the type" which kind of means "deducing the type". When we explicitly specify the type, normal conversion rules apply and so there is no "determining the type" of `T`. That is, when we explicity specify the template type argument, we are saying/specifying with 100% certainty that this is the type of `T`.

Comment: @AnoopRana I agree, it could be worded better. It's also weird that they use a different style of wording for "functions/arrays are replaced with pointers". I believe the part you're quoting only applies to NTTP, since it's right after a paragraph dealing with those (or, in the [same paragraph](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#6) in the latest draft). Also type parameters don't really "have" types, they "are" (or "represent"?) types. Also this wording existed even in C++11, which didn't have type deduction for NTTP....

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I agree that template type parameter are "types" themselves so it doesn't make much sense to say "determining its type". A more sensical phrase IMO would be "determining the type"? . Also, i am aware that C++11 didn't have type deduction for NTTP. But i didn't get your point when you said: *"the comparison with type parameters doesn't work"*. I mean which comparison you're talking about here. Is it between the type of NTTP and the template type parameter or something else.

Comment: I've edited the comment since you replied. :) Maybe I misunderstood you, I though you were saying that "this has to apply only when deducing the type, since it clearly doesn't apply when manually specifying type parameters", and I'm saying that it only applies to NTTP (and applies always, not only when deducing).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes i am saying that temp.param#5 applies when "determining the template parameter's type". By determining i interpret "deducing".Moreover, since in temp.param#5 they've used the term "template parameter" instead of "non-type template parameter",I take that they're talking in general(including the "type parameter" as well as "type of non-type").But since in C++11 there was no type deduction for NTTP, so temp.param#5 naturally(meaning the condition "determining its type isn't satisfied") excludes NTTP. But from C++17, it includes NTTP. i.e., in C++17, temp.param#5 applies to both.

Comment: It clearly doesn't apply to type parameters, since there are ways to deduce them as `const`. I still think that since it's in a paragraph dealing with NTTP, it only applies to NTTP, and since it was introduced before NTTP type deduction, it can't be limited to deduction...

Answer (score 0):

To my current understanding of templates, this is what should happen:

##### Point 1

From [temp.param#5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.param#5):

> The top-level cv-qualifiers on the template-parameter are ignored **when determining its type.**

On the first glance it seems that when applied to the given snippet, `a` should be `int` instead of `const int`.

But note the emphasis on the highlighted part in the above quoted statement. In particular, my interpretation of this(the phrase "when determining") is that the top-level cv-qualifiers are dropped **when deducing the template parameter and so not when the template arguments are explicitly specified**.

And since in my given snippet, we are explicitly specifying the template argument, there is no template argument deduction(TAD) here. Thus, the dropping of the top-level cv-qualifiers due to the above quoted [temp.param#5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.param#5) does not happen. Meaning the type of `a` is `const int` instead of `int`. **This would suggest that GCC is correct** in rejecting the code since we should provide an initializer for the `const` variable named `p`.

Note that i may be wrong in interpreting [temp.param#5] above.

---

##### Point 2

But from [temp.param#6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.param#6):

> **A non-type non-reference template-parameter is a prvalue**. It shall not be assigned to or in any other way have its value changed.

Moreover, from [expr#6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr#6):

> If a prvalue initially has the type “cv T”, where T is a cv-unqualified non-class, non-array type, the type of the expression is **adjusted to T prior to any further analysis**.

When applying [temp.param#6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.param#6) and [expr#6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr#6) to the given snippet, it means that `a`(a prvalue) will finally be of type `int` instead of `const int`. That is, **this suggest that MSVC and Clang are correct** in accepting the code, since `p` is a non-const `int`.

So, given the above analysis, my thinking is that the code is valid and so msvc and clang are correct in accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [temp.param#5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.param#5) still applies here and nothing else is needed. Let's rewrite your example to make it easier to reason about:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    template<T a>
    static void f()
    {
          decltype(a) p;
    }
};

int main()
{
     Foo<const int>::f<0>();
}
```

So we have a template `Foo` and a function template `f()` as 2 separate entities with separated template headers. Now if we instantiate `Foo<const int>` we get the following **non-template**:

```
struct Foo
{
    template<const int a>
    static void f()
    {
          decltype(a) p;
    }
};
```

And `f()` is still a function template and according to the cited standard reference `decltype(a)` should produce `int`.

You might argue that your example is different and while it is different in tokens it is not different in meaning. The non-type parameter of the original `f` is not deducible (doesn't have `auto` anywhere) it is pretty clearly specified to be of type `T`. It just so happens that `T` is something not available at the moment so until `T` is somehow specified, non-type parameter `a` makes no sense, it doesn't exist. Once you specified `T` it became a non-type parameter and we can apply whatever we should apply to it being an NTP.